# How to disable optical drive

Tags: windows-7, optical-drive

I have a Dell XPS M1530 laptop. The drive has a blank disk in it, but can't discharge the disk. The drive just keeps cycling trying to eject the disk about every 30 seconds. How can I disable the drive, e.g. cut power to the drive or change settings so that the drive no longer functions? I don't want to take the computer completely apart to replace the drive.

Thanks

Comment: Only thing you can do is remove or unplug the drive from the laptop, which requires some disassembly.

Comment: Your service manual...http://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_xps_laptop/xps-m1530_service%20manual_en-us.pdf

Comment: Does it happen with any and every disk or a specific disk?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, disk trys like this will have a small hole in the side next to the eject button.

If you bend a paperclip, and stick it in the hole, this will push against a manual release of the try.

Then you can just remove the disk.

[Like this.](https://www.google.com/search?q=disk%20drive%20eject%20pin&tbm=isch)

Comment: Thanks Matt. Unfortunately, this drive does not have a tray or the hole. I searched BIOS and also Control Panel-System-Advanced. I deleted the Samsung driver, but those attempts also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

As others suggest, repairing/replacing the optical drive is best. But until then, have you tried disabling the drive in the BIOS as a temp fix?

Many laptop's BIOS settings allow you to completely disable it at the BIOS level before the OS takes over, but keep in mind that's where you'll get lots of complaints about HW not functioning.

Comment: Thanks HoftHome. I did go through the BIOS, but was unable to find any control for the optical drive other than repositioning start order.